# getting the template name and the time it takes to render in a middleware based on a url

Tags: django, django-middleware

I want to write a middleware that would tell me the name of the template being rendered and the time it took, for the database queries for that particular view. 
Django Debug Toolbar does the same, but due to custom request and response object written i am not able to get that working. 
So i thought of writing a custom middleware that would do the same for me on a url appended with some get request variable.
Say `127.0.0.1/index/polls` gives me all the polls. 
If i try `127.0.0.1/index/polls/?my_tool` it would invoke a url, and i would get the data.

Any suggestions on how to implement it? Is there a working example?

Comment: Have you looked at django's debug context processor https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-debug

Comment: the request/response is custom hence context processors are not working its a legacy code. custom middleware is the only soln. besides i want not exactly on the url but the url with some get as shown above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could infer that you need some debug tool for development, in that case I would suggest [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar), otherwise, if you really need the middleware you always can look at the code of [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar). :)

If I´ve got to write that by myself, I would write a couple of classes (in debug toolbar are called panels) that inherits from [template](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/debug_toolbar/panels/template.py) and [timer](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/debug_toolbar/panels/timer.py), and override the method `process_response` for log or print the info that I need.

Even you can look into the [middleware of debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar/blob/master/debug_toolbar/middleware.py) and picture an idea of how it works